# Get friends of friends in PHP and MYSQL with this table structure

Tags: php, mysql

In a social networking project, I would like to get random friends of friends in order to suggest to users like the one Facebook has. The number of suggested users is dynamic. But our table's fields are as follows:

`inviter_id`, `friend_id`, `status`

So the `user id` can be either in `inviter_id` or `friend_id`, `status 2` shows that the friend request is accepted and they are currently friends.

Can anyone please help me with a decent solution?

I already have one, which definitely slows down the website as it gets bigger and heavier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about showing us your solution so we know what NOT to suggest? And a word about what you understand by "bigger and heavier" would also be useful. 100 Users? 100.000.000?

Comment: Do you have a (PRIMARY KEY) index on (inviter_id,friend_id)? Can you have both (2,1,1) and (1,2,1) ?

Comment: @TheChaos I solved it with lines of php code but needed a single query like the one our friend M.S. wrote below. Thanks for caring.

Comment: @Strawberry yes those two field are PRIMARY KEY. It is solved now thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (
    (SELECT t1.inviter_id as id FROM TableName t1 LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.friend_id = t2.inviter_id WHERE t1.status = 1 AND t2.status=1 AND t2.friend_id = UserId)
    UNION
    (SELECT t1.inviter_id as id FROM TableName t1 LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.friend_id = t2.friend_id WHERE t1.status = 1 AND t2.status=1 AND t2.inviter_id = UserId)
    UNION
    (SELECT t1.friend_id as id FROM TableName t1 LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.inviter_id = t2.inviter_id WHERE t1.status = 1 AND t2.status=1 AND t2.friend_id = UserId)
    UNION
    (SELECT t1.friend_id as id FROM TableName t1 LEFT JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.inviter_id = t2.friend_id WHERE t1.status = 1 AND t2.status=1 AND t2.inviter_id = UserId)
) as temp WHERE id != UserId AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (friend_id = id AND inviter_id=UserId) OR (inviter_id = id AND friend_id=UserId))
```

(Replace TableName with your table's name and UserId with the target user/variable).

Linkt to my test/example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddbec/2

Comment: I suspect that it can be done with a little less code!

Comment: @Strawberry I agree to that, but imo there was not enough information for it, and it was the first thing that came in my mind.

Comment: Well, I can't argue with that!